# Keyboard reopen for no reason

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

The main activity of my application have a classique search button in the ABS

When i touch it it expand an EditView and open the keyboard

Then you tap some search words, valid, it open a new search activity without finishing the main activity

after you've done your search you touch back and return to main activity

Here the edittext is retracted and the keyboard hidden, BUT it open itself for no reason !!

**In the menu.xml file**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/view_menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="recherche"/>
```

**The view_menu_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

**In the manifest.xml**

```
   <!-- Main -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.ActivityMain"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
```

**In MainActivity.java :**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        mSearchEdit = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        // search menuitem
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Do something when collapsed
                closeKeyboardFocus();
                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                if (mSearchEdit.requestFocus()) {
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                }
                openKeyboard();
                return true; // Return true to expand action view
            }
        });
        mSearchEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    moveToSearchActivity(v.getText().toString(), true);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

public void openKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}

public void closeKeyboardFocus() {
    // Close keyboard
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    // check if no view has focus:
    View v = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null)
        return;
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

EDIT1 :

For now i just use this in onResume() to prevent the keyboard from openning (but i don't think this is a good solution)

```
// hide the keyboard simple trick
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Does the edit text get focus automatically? I remember an issue with that before.

Comment: when the edittext expand i have to open the keyboard manually but that's all so i guess the editview take the focus by itself